# Linux, Apache, PHP - need solution for document upload, edit, and version control

Tags: php, linux, apache, web-applications

I am developing an internal website that is running Linux, Apache, PHP and CodeIgniter. I need to find a solution to satisfy the following:

- Document upload. (Think word docs, excel docs and pdfs)
- Document edit/checkout capabilities.
- Document version control (who made what changes when to this document)
- Wiki capabilities. (view, edit, create text for certain pages within the site)

Each of these things will be native within the intranet site. I do not want to link to another system to conduct the above tasks. I want all of the controls within the site itself.

I considered turning up sharepoint and mediawiki and using API calls to interact with it. However sharepoint doesn't play nice with Linux when it comes to APIs. Mediawiki has a horrible set of tools to add text stylizing. Making something bold/italics/underline is not intuitive at all.

Is there a plugin for apache which acts as a CMS backend? Is there some project that I could use to help me here? I am willing to build it from scratch but I also want to be smart about it. Any ideas what to use here?

Comment: Did you consider dropbox or github ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a "document management system" and there are dozens of open-source free ones available. Do not invent one from scratch. You will spend months and will be stuck maintaining this system for years

If you want WYSIWYG editing, consider TinyMCE or CKEditor, both are great, and relatively easy to integrate into whatever backend.